# How to upload large apps made in unity3d to Apple's MDM?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to Upload an app to Apples MDM so that the app can be distributed to the devices that are linked to the MDM account.

When I try to upload the app to MDM It just errors with a message that says `Unable to Download App  xxxx could not be installed at this time.`

I suspected that it has something to do with the size of the app, which is 6GB due to have video files as a part of the app.

**The app must be able to work without internet connection once the user has installed the app*

Is there a maximum size for an app to be uploaded to Apple's MDM?

Should data such as videos be apart of an app deployment or should the data be downloaded once the app is installed?

Comment: You should never compile large assets into the ipa (apk, exe, etc). They should be downloaded separately (they can still be accessed without Internet because they're downloaded and saved locally).

Comment: How exactly is this related to Unity?

Comment: @Draco18s why is that?  I put all of my 3d models inside my app at compile time, some are quite large, should I not be doing that?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 are you able to upload the project to Apple's MDM?

Comment: @user3558639 I have never tried, but I was asking the general question why you should never compile large assets into the final executable file.  I had never heard this before.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I mean, you don't have to put models in at compile time either. The project I'm working on now *specifically* won't have the 3D assets bundled into the application. The reason to remove large files (notably, audio and video assets) is because it bloats the executable size.